# alternate of group_concat function in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I need some comma separated values for one of my column :

```
Input :

id    status
1.    pause
1.    start
1.    running
2.    pause
3.    pause

Output:
id. status
1.  pause,start,running
2.  pause
3.  pause
```

I do not want to use the group_concat function here as in future in it can be possible that will be using another type of database (sql/nosql).Can anyone help me to use any alternate method?

Comment: The only alternate way would be to do it in client code, and not in the database. The best solution is to use `GROUP_CONCAT`, but isolate the part of your code that talks to the database so you can switch it out for another implementation.

Comment: We need to know what the other database/system is in order to give you a workaround for `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Recursive CTE which combines separate values to solid CSV one-by-one.

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS (
    SELECT id, status, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) rn
    FROM test
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT id, rn,
           CAST(status AS CHAR(65535)) csv
    FROM cte1
    WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT cte1.id, cte1.rn,
           CONCAT_WS(',', cte2.csv, cte1.status)
    FROM cte2
    JOIN cte1 ON cte1.id = cte2.id AND cte1.rn = cte2.rn + 1
),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT id, csv, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rn DESC) rn
    FROM cte2
)
SELECT id, csv 
FROM cte3
WHERE rn = 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0713abe3711c98c91dd1ceadb533e968

Another DBMSs needs minimal changes when adapting this query. Removing `RECURSIVE` from `WITH` clause definition, replacing `CONCAT_WS()` with according function (or maybe using common concatenation if `status`is not nullable), removing explicit CAST in recursive CTE or changing the datatype...

PS. Another DBMSs have the function which is an analog of GROUP_CONCAT() in MySQL, or at least they have some specific constructions/methods for to perform such task.

Comment: "Another DBMSs needs minimal changes when adapting this query" — many older SQL databases do not have access to recursive CTEs, and NoSQL ones (that OP indicates being a possibility) definitely do not (they might have a comparable capability, but by definition it would not be in SQL syntax). As you say in your post scriptum, since an adaptation is necessary either way, might as well go with the simpler and more readable aggregate concat function. This is academically interesting and educational, but I would not have used it in my code.